# How can a cmdlet determine if it is if it is being called from a job or RunSpace?

Tags: powershell

I am writing some cmdlets , that need to do some extra things if they are being called from the context of a job or RunSpace ?

If these cmdlets are not running from a Job or RunSpace the progress and status is on the console.  But if they are running in the context of a Job or RunSpace , that is reported through a file.  Instead of asking the user to do something else, I want to auto detect this case.

Comment: Maybe digging into `Trace-Command` can give you some info into what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can base your decision on the value of `$Host.Name` (in PowerShell code) / the `.Name` property of the [`.Host` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscmdlet.host) of the cmdlet base class, `PSCmdlet` (in C# code implementing a cmdlet), which is the name of the component hosting PowerShell:<sup>[1]</sup>

- PowerShell code:

```
$outputToFile = $Host.Name -in 'ServerRemoteHost', 'Default Host'
```

- C# code (in a class derived from [`PSCmdlet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet)):

```
bool outputToFile = Host.Name == "ServerRemoteHost" || Host.Name == "Default Host";
```

- String `ServerRemoteHost` is reported for calls via [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote_FAQ) / [background jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs).
- String `Default Host` is reported when you use the [PowerShell SDK (runspace)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/windows-powershel) / [thread jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Thread_Jobs).

---

<sup>[1] The [automatic `$Host` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#host) reports the current PowerShell host, which is a .NET class derived from [`System.Management.Automation.Host.PSHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Host.PSHost).</sup>

Comment: So this works From runspace $host.name == "Default Host" from ISE == "Windows PowerShell ISE Host" , and from cmd PowerShell == "ConsoleHost"

Comment: The  $host.name solves the issue . From runspace $host.name == "Default Host" from ISE == "Windows PowerShell ISE Host" , and from cmd PowerShell == "ConsoleHost". So in my cmdlet I will check $host.name == 'Default Host' I am in run space.